# Auto-Compile Bash Script not working

Tags: java, bash, shell, scripting, terminal

Simply put, I want to manually compile Java files through the command line, but don't want to do it for each directory. I tried to write this script but it doesn't seem to work.

```
CUR=$PWD                              # save workspace directory to return
for line in `find -type d -name src`  # find and loop through src paths
do
    eval cd $line                     # go to src
    eval javac *.java
    eval jar *.class                  # I need to have a jar for my project
    eval mv ../bin/                   
    cd $CUR
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `eval` at all in that script.

But one problem is probably that your source directories are not all called `src` (or are they?) What is your directory structure like?

Also you probably need to have a single jar for your project, not multiple jars, so that bit won't work either.

You should probably look into using a real Java build tool such as Ant or Maven; they solved this problem over a decade ago.

Comment: Also the jar command needs parameters, like cf or cvf, and unless all the source file are in the default package, the wildcard won't work..

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements to your existing script:

```
for line in $(find -type d -name src)  # find and loop through src paths
do
    (
    cd $line                     # go to src
    javac *.java
    jar *.class                  # I need to have a jar for my project
    mv ../bin/                   
    )
done
```

Use parenthesis to execute the inner part in a subshell and avoid `cd` issues. Also I see no reason for `eval`.

Are you sure all your java files are all directly in a folder called `src` without any package structure? Are you sure they need no further classpath information to compile?

What exactly is the problem, that makes you think it does not work?

Is there a good reason, why you are not using grade, maven, or ant to build your project?

(Feel free to simply update the question as a response to the questions.)